# Checking if apk's contain malicious software

Tags: mobile

Is there a programmatic way to check if a given mobile application executable is malicious through some sort of lookup service? 
I have used Virustotal for desktop malware, does it work for mobile malware as well? Are there other standards for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virus Total has malicious APKs as well, I'm sure you're aware of how to use their API if you've used them for desktop. You might also use [Anubis](https://anubis.iseclab.org/).

Example:

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/23a6384fc22e1dc10e49223292415c91cb7fc4540f7feae86c61165420009af7/analysis/

To declare an apk malicious that requires actual analysis. Some good resources to get started there might be [Santoku](https://santoku-linux.com/) or [ARE](https://www.honeynet.org/node/783).